# Person did not receive the amount of bitcoin I sent

Tags: transactions

I sent $4300 in bitcoin to my friend and he only received $415. I'm so upset because I lost over $3500.  Is there any way to get this corrected?

Comment: With bitcoin blockchain, **this event doesn't possible** receive the partial amount.

Comment: I have a record showing how much I sent and the amount received was sent to me in a screenshot. It most certainly did happen.

Comment: This sounds like a misunderstanding. Could you give us a bit more information to work with like for example a transaction id, or some screenshots of your send and the receive?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the transaction you sent, displayed by a block explorer:

[image]

It can be seen that the transaction created two outputs:

1AHpgNCRHg41wmX4SWvsA8eq7wcN6gPKMi 0.59573100 BTC

1LSpWLjsQS3Z5j49gFXNy8YYHz8sMjUMr4 0.00046671 BTC

I assume that the `1AHpg..` address is what you paid your friend, and the other address is your change. But in any case, neither of the outputs is ~$400 in value currently, so your friend is mistaken/lying to you about what they received (or they are using some *extremely* broken wallet software).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your transaction on an explorer like blockstream.info.  There, you will see what was the inputs and outputs of your transaction.

The most likely case (assuming you sent to the correct address) is that you sent an incorrect amount.  Even in that case the change will come back to you.  Another possibility is that you sent the transaction with a massive fee.

You just need to see the transaction details on an explorer to figure out what happened.

Comment: I did find it on blockchain explorer. It shows I sent $4360.95 and it says "received" same amount.

Comment: How would I send transaction with a massive fee?  I just typed in the amount & sent. I know nothing about fees.

Comment: Hash
1e9930c7b881056437e69a0e766f6f22925d4ace3085bb0b13be9fb21550def2
2019-11-22 16:50
1Lnv7H46pCeLu9SV57CvMWsVV5Xn6YKhcL
0.32184759 BTC
1PErhkxZezRXauet9cFCTRFU59PrPXde3h
0.16231033 BTC
1PErhkxZezRXauet9cFCTRFU59PrPXde3h
0.07480060 BTC
1PErhkxZezRXauet9cFCTRFU59PrPXde3h
0.03738747 BTC
1AHpgNCRHg41wmX4SWvsA8eq7wcN6gPKMi
0.59573100 BTC
1LSpWLjsQS3Z5j49gFXNy8YYHz8sMjUMr4
0.00046671 BTC

Answer (score 0):

Transaction Number `1e9930c7b881056437e69a0e766f6f22925d4ace3085bb0b13be9fb21550def2`
was the transfer of `0.59619` BitCoin.

At November 2019 prices, that was about $4,500.

The result of the transfer was `0.5957` (approx $4,300) to Address `1AHpgNCRHg41wmX4SWvsA8eq7wcN6gPKMi`.

Assuming that was the address of your "friend", they received the amount due.

Is it possible you are being scammed by someone pretending to be a friend?